# A way to copy two ranges from excel to Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Ok, so I have 16 references in a dropdown list, located at C10 on my spreadsheet, this alters the information in the ranges A1:Q39, after which I want range A1:Q39 and range A41:Q69 to be copied as pictures to individual slides on a powerpoint presentation.

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Q39")
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A41:Q69")

    On Error Resume Next
        Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
        Err.Clear
        If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)
    Cells(10, 3) = "2018A"
    rng.Copy
    mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=3
Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    myShape.Left = 56
    myShape.Top = 52
    PowerPointApp.Visible = True
    PowerPointApp.Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)
    rng2.Copy
    mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=3
Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    myShape.Left = 56
    myShape.Top = 100

PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

This is what I have so far, this just gets repeated 16 times for the reference that's being altered by Cells(10, 3).
When I try to run the macro, it might work for a few of those references but I usually get a runtime error "shapes.pastespecial : Invalid request. The specified data type is unavailable" I'm, as you can tell, quite inexperienced when it comes to VBA, but I'm hoping someone might be able to shed some light on this for me? If you need any more information, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I/O operations, like using the clipboard and saving files, usually run more slowly than your code does. So you need to slow it down using Sleep, Wait or DoEvents. Google those for the details of how to do that.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you.